# Reading muilti line path from document and performing actions

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a script that I'm trying to run on a master document. The script looks at a txt doc with the full file name and path encased in double quotes. Then it takes the filename and parent folder (because the full folder structure wont match) and searches the master document. Then it outputs the result into another text document This is what I have so far and it works if I place the quoted files directly into the string but when I try to get it to read from a file containing the quoted files it breaks

Example source text file to be read from:

`"This-is/An-Example-pFa/ati4_review_2014033434314-15532223545/article19_20140314-155812_REVIEW.JPG"
"This-is/An-Example-pFa/ati4_review_2014033434314-15532223545/article19_20140314-155812_REVIEW.JPG"
"This-is/An-Example-pFa/ati4_review_2014033434314-15532223545/article19_20140314-155812_REVIEW.JPG"`

```
#!/bin/bash

AWS="/home/user/Documents/awslist.csv" #variable for master document
LSFLDR=$(while read k; do echo "$k";   #variable to read source text file
done < /home/user/Documents/FP.txt)    
strings=(
$LSFLDR                                   
)


for i in "${strings[@]}";
do (
VAR="$i"                                 #variable for line in source text file
DIR="$(basename "$(dirname "$VAR")")"    #variable to locate parent folder
FIL=$(basename "${VAR}")         #variable to locate file name
CMP="${DIR}"\/"${FIL}"           #variable to search master document
if grep -q "$CMP" $AWS;          #searching master document for parent folder and file name
then
       echo $i found >> /home/user/Documents/Scanresults.txt
else
       echo $i not found >> /home/user/Documents/Scanresults.txt
fi

)
done
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when you try to get it to reference a file"?

Comment: Sorry about that, I mean that instead of placing the quoted text directly in the string, If I place it in a file and try to get the script to read that file it breaks. The "referenced file" would be the text document containing the full file path surrounded in quotes.

Comment: If you would simply do this "by hand" in the shell and examine your variables, your problem will become immediately apparent: While the quotes get stripped by shell parsing when you place filenames "directly into the string", this **does not happen** when you read and process from the file. Remove the quotes from the file and try again.

Comment: The quotes in the bash script have a special meaning.  When you read them out of a file, they are literal quote characters and will be part of the variable.  Take the quotes out of the file will be a good start

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had quotes in because some of the filenames have spaces but removed the quotes from the file and it is still only processing it literally line by line, even though the path/names extend into two or three lines.

Comment: are you sure each item of interest is really on 2 lines? You can get that impression looking at a file in a editor like `vim`, but its really all in one. Try `cat -vet myFile`. Do you see `$` 2x for each item of interest? If yes, then you are correct. If only one `$` per IOI, then you really have the data split across lines. Which begs the Q, why!? It will be much easier to go back to the source of that file and figure out a way to have the complete path and filename all on one line. Else you can write a small `awk` filter that fixes the data. Busy now, can't give you an example, ......

Comment: Oh, and if you saw `^M$` at the end of each line, then run `dos2unix myFile` and avoid a whole class of problems ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) -- the way you are populating the `strings` array is horrifying.

If you want to populate an array with the lines of a file:

```sh
mapfile -t strings < filename
```

If you just want to *iterate* over the lines of a file (don't have to read the whole file into memory):

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
   do_something_with "$line"
done < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Glenn! Yes, I'm sure my script made you cringe lol. The mapfile was exactly what I needed to get it working!